# Input Value Attribute Not Showing In Search Bar

Tags: html, searchbar

```
 <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="/search/"> 
   <input type="text" name="q" id="q"  value="" placeholder="Search Your Keyword...">
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is the search bar works perfectly but on loading the search bar is not showing the term which is being searched.

Example: If I search **overflow** the result will show but the search bar will show the placeholder and not the value.

Kindly let me know what mistake I have made here.

Thank you.

Comment: what happens when you search something? will the site be reloaded? if that is the case, you need to manually input your searchterm into the input field, after loading the page

Comment: Yes it reloads and shows the result on different page that is Search Page.

I need like this: https://www.wpbeginner.com/search/

When you search something it shows the result and same time the search term is there in search box

My setup is same like WPBeginner just that value attribute is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```html
  <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="/search/"> 
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Search Your Keyword...">
        <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit">Search</button>
       </form>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: No, it's still giving the same result and nothing changes.

Reference Website: https://www.wpbeginner.com/search/

When you search something it shows the result and same time the search term is there in search box My setup is same like WPBeginner just that value attribute is not working